# How to create a desktop app for the existing web application?

Tags: java, spring, javafx, desktop-application

Well, I've tried to do some researches before creating a question but only a little has been found.

Basically, I have got a Spring-based web application. Apparently, you can navigate through web application using HTTP requests and URLs. If you want to edit a user you do a `GET` request `/users/edit/{id}` and a new page appears. Then you make some changes to the user and do a `POST` request `/users/edit/{id}` and let's say the main page appears.

So, now I need to create a desktop application which can do the same things. 
Do I need to rewrite the whole app to port it on the desktop? Is it possible somehow to do sort of *HTTP* requests from the desktop app to the server, then get a response and process it? Or perhaps there is a proper way to do it?

I feel like it's a big topic but **I only need** you to **point me** in the right direction as I'm lacking experience in creating both desktop and web applications together *(I'd say, I have never ported app from web to desktop and vice verse)*.

Earlier I created a few apps using JavaFX and I want to use it again as my GUI platform for the desktop app.

Comment: Why don't you go for a solution like Electron

Comment: Plain Java: `java.net.HttpURLConnection`; if you use Spring dependencies: `RestTemplate` or as i really recommend like @Sand did: use Electron, since you really do not want multiple code bases that basically acomplish the same thing.

Comment: Well, I'll have a look at Electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for a solution like, [**Electron**](https://electronjs.org/).

It's a framework for creating native applications with web technologies like `JavaScript`, `HTML`, and `CSS`. It uses `Chromium` and `Node.js`. You can develop your desktop GUI applications using front and back end components originally developed for your web application.

I'm just pointing you a way. You can look in to this solution and it's also open-source.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. Using Electron I can still do requests to the server where the back-end does its work? And the only thing I need to do is to create a front-end for the desktop app.

Comment: Exactly. Modern app development approaches create a backend which does all stuff and then multiple frontends can be created that consume the same HTTP API. Http is no longer reserved for the Web. For example, if you ever wanted to create a mobile app the same backend would still be the same and you'll need to focus only in creating a nice UI for the device.

Comment: @AlexRoig well, thanks. But what if I want to create a desktop app with the ability to go offline mode? How would it use HTTP API? Is it the option when I need to recreate backend for desktop standalone application?

Comment: That's tricky but possible. Modern browsers have different persistance options such as LocalStorage, SessionStorage, IndexedDB and Web SQL. You can fetch the data while connection is there and persist the data on the browser's DB. If Internet connection is active, work directly with the API, if not, query the local data. Also you can create a queue to persist of data that cannot be saved while working offline.

Comment: @AlexRoig It feels like a really huge amount of work. But thanks for the clarification. I guess, I'll have to make more researches on this topic.

Comment: It's complicated and requires some additional work but the result is worth it. And also, if you worked with a classic desktop framework you'd need to develop some similar technique to keep a local copy of the database to work with in case there's no connection to the server. As personal advice, never ever establish a SQL connection from client to the server directly. Latency of Internet is too much for SQL to work smoothly and will make your app useless.

Comment: Finally, check the Service Workers. They'll help you with the caching and the transition from online to offline and viceversa. There are some examples out there: https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers

Answer (score 0):

If you were about to develop the frontend from scratch I'd recommend you to use something like `Ionic Framework` where in the latest beta 4 allows you to write once run everywhere (web, PWA, desktop with Electron, and build native build for iOS and Android). 
Basically Ionic is an Angular 7 library/superset that allows you to create mobile apps based on a webview. This webview can be embedded and run on any device in a native way.

Even though the same codebase can be run on multiple devices you can customise the look and feel on each platform and access through Cordova, Electron or Capacitor the native device capabilities and hardware.

If you don't want to rewrite the web client, you can use any desktop framework with the preferred language you want. Any modern language/framework will allow you to make HTTP requests against your backend and get the data through your API.
Honestly, nowadays I'd day that JavaFX is not the best option out there and I'd recommend you to go through the web-based approach.

Good luck!